# Default Switch Statement Always Executes?

Tags: c++, c

I am a bit confused as to why I always get the default case in this simple program. Any help would be appreciated...

```
#include <stdio.h>

char conversion(letter)
{
   switch(letter)
   {
       case 'A': 
            printf("a\n");
            break;

       case 'B': 
            printf("b\n");
            break;

       default: 
            printf("Not an upper case letter!\n");
            break;
   }         
   return letter;         
}


int main()
{
   char character;
   while ((character = getchar()) != '0')
         conversion(character);
}
```

Comment: `char conversion(letter)` there's a type specifier missing - this isn't legal C++.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging info (on Linux `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn to use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: Your default case could do `printf("(%c) is Not an upper case letter!\n", letter);` and see what the input is atleast

Comment: This code shouldn't compile: neither in C nor in C++ as the argument `letter` has no type.

Comment: @DietmarKühl It's legal in C89

Comment: and what is your later `printf` printing? Is it printing A, B even after going to default? if not, yes need to figure why?

Comment: @nos technically not after C99 but gcc and clang allow it

Comment: @nos: fair enough but C90 is out of date quite a while (I realize that not everybody has realized that the standard was updated a few times since C90, though).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description the `default` case is hit by the newline character following the uppercase letter you enter: the whitespace characters, e.g., the `'\n'` character resulting from the newline, will be processed by your `switch()`. You might want to sort spaces out using `isspace()` (declared in `<ctype.h>`):

```
if (!isspace((unsigned char)c)) {
    switch (c) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char conversion(letter)
{
   if (!isspace((unsigned char)letter))
   {
       switch(letter)
       {
           case 'A': 
                printf("a\n");
                break;
           
           case 'B': 
                printf("b\n");
                break;
           
           default: 
                printf("Not an upper case letter!\n");
                break;
       }         
       return letter; 
   }        
}

int main()
{
   char character;
   while ((character = getchar()) != '0')
         conversion(character);
}

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with the switch-case but the getchar().

Everytime you hit return (ENTER key), there's an extra newline character (`\n`) which is again passed to the function and it goes to default case since it's neither `'A'` nor `'B'`.

You could modify the loop to:

```
  while ((character = getchar()) != '0')
   {
         getchar();
         conversion(character);
   }
```

so that the newline is consumed.

Comment: Thanks - I completely missed the inclusion of the Enter key character (\n, new line)... :-)

Comment: Yes Agree, but then he should see two iterations and in one switch should work and other get `\n` right? but from his question, i don't think thats what is happening.

Comment: @joe That's what happens here. So you downvote whenever *you* don't understand something?

Comment: @Asterix Yes. If you want to know what's being passed the best place is to print in the default case so you know exactly what's passed. Btw, change `char conversion(letter)` to `char conversion(int letter)` which is valid only in C89 mode not in C99 or C11. In C89 a parameter with type defaults to int. Hence it works for you. But in general, you shouldn't learning/using things that are removed/deprecated in the recent C standards.

Comment: Good point. I was doing an exercise in K&R (1st edition, 1978).

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((character = getchar()) != '0')
```

Runs the code in the while loop on every character inputted by the user. When you hit `A` followed by your return key, you're actually inputting `A\n`, which is two characters, causing it to call the `conversion` twice with `A` and `\n` as arguments, respectively.